# How to mirror a vector along a surface?

Tags: math, vector

Hi everyone I couldn't find any solution about this so I wanted to ask this on the forum.

While referencing the image below, I have a curve AB and I want to mirror the direction vector dB along the curve's surface. I only want the mirrored direction. So I need to use that curve as an axis to mirror that direction.
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1fJG.jpg)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the question. You are asking about reflecting a vector along a surface, but in the description you talk about a curve. Moreover, in the picture, the two vectors seems to lie on two different points in space. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Also, do you know the normal of the surface at the point where `dB` lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2D Curve**

Assuming that you have the normalized tangent `t = normalize(a-b)`, use the following formula, where `·` is the dot product:

`dA = dB - 2*t*(dB·t)`

A bit of explanation: `t*(dB·t)` is the tangential component. Remove it once will give the normal component, a removing it twice will reverse the tangantial component, thus resulting in the reflected vector.

**3D Surface**

Assuming that you have the normal `n` of the surface, use the following formula:

`dA = -(dB - n*(dB·n)) + n*(dB·n)`

which can be simplified to `dA = -dB + 2*n*(dB·n)`.

A bit of explanation: `n*(dB·n)` is the normal component. We first remove it from `dB` since we want to preserve it. `dB - n*(dB·n)` is thus the tangential component. Then, we negate the tangential component, and we add the normal component back to obtain the reflected vector.

Comment: I don't have the normal of the surface , but I do have its direction normalized(B-A)

Comment: @TristanG I assumed that it was a 3D surface, but I think I misinterpreted the question. Is it a 2D curve in the plane, i.e., with 2D coordinates?

Comment: @TristanG I edited the answer to provide both versions, which are very similar in logic and can be used in many different cases.

Comment: Thank you! You definitely helped me. I tried it in code and it works perfectly! Thanks for the explanations!

Comment: Glad that I could help you! :) If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as "Accepted".